# JQuery - Add a mouse-event listener to a class

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="teamMain">
    <div class="teamScroll">
        PRIMO
    </div>

    <div class="teamScroll">
        SECONDO
    </div>

    <div class="teamScroll">
        TERZO
    </div>
</div>
```

And i'd like to add a sort of listener (such mouseover or mouseout) for each of this div, by taking the class *teamScroll* as reference.

I know there is *delegate* method, but it works only with **jquery-1.4.2** version (which, as posted time ago for another [problem](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-problem-with-last-version-and-ie)) broke some functions with IE6.

There is other way to do this without put N listener for N div?

Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a normal [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) handler, like this:

```
$(".teamScroll").hover(function() {
  //mouse on the item
}, function() {
  //mouse off the item
});
```

That's the way that always works (but does `2n` handlers like you're asking about), assuming 1.4.2 isn't an option...if you're on at least 1.3.2, there's [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) like this:

```
$(".teamScroll").live("mouseenter", function() {
  //mouse on the item
}).live("mouseleave", function() {
  //mouse off the item
});
```

The difference here is that [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) runs an extra selector and the event bubbles all the way up to `document`...as well as it *actually* maps to `mouseover` and `mouseout` under the covers, which is often undesirable.

Instead, I'd suggest the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) route, and seeing if jQuery 1.4.4 fixes the issue you have in 1.4.2, there were several AJAX tweaks in 1.4.3/1.4.4.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('.teamScroll').bind('onmouseover', function() {
  alert('Mouseover');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.teamScroll').mouseover(function(){

});
```